# Phrase for "something is like in the books"

Tags: phrase-request

I am looking for phrase which expresses that a certain thing just like you heard it in class, or red it in a book, it is the typical example for a certain thing.
For example an apple is a fruit, when you say "fruit", for lots of people apple will come to mind. So for a fruit apple is this phrase.

Comment: It is a bit unclear what exactly you're asking.  Perhaps "common knowledge" is what you're looking for...

Comment: Not quite, the emphasis should be on the association of the two items. That a is associated to b commonly. That a is the most common example for b, which comes in your mind.

Comment: You can probably call it "immediate association", "natural association" or "commonly associated terms"...

Comment: Will "universal truth"do?

Answer (score 3):

*Textbook example* or *textbook case* may come close to what you are asking for.

> If you say that something is a textbook case or example, you are emphasizing that it provides a clear example of a type of situation or event.
>   ADJ n    (emphasis)   The house is a textbook example of medieval domestic architecture...

You can search "textbook example define" and find several such definitions.

Answer (score 0):

One word for that is *archetype*: ["the original pattern or model of which all things of the same type are representations or copies :  prototype; also :  a perfect example"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/archetype)
or
 ["having all the important qualities that make somebody/something a typical example of a particular kind of person or thing."](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/archetypal)

The adjective form of the word is archetypal, so you might say "The apple is the archetype of fruit" or "The apple is the archetypal fruit".

"Archetype" is a fairly advanced and uncommon word, though, so you might want to use a simpler word or phrase, like "the typical example" that you use in your original post.